# PHP - The archieve is either in unknown format or damaged

Tags: php

I've got a website that everybody can download rar or pdf files.

```
function download_file($download_url)
 {
   if( headers_sent())
     die('Headers Sent');


    if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression'))
     ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');


  if(file_exists($download_url))
 {

$fsize = filesize($download_url);
$path_parts = pathinfo($download_url);
$ext = strtolower($path_parts["extension"]);

switch ($ext) 
{
  case "pdf": $ctype="application/pdf"; break;
  //case "exe": $ctype="application/octet-stream"; break;
  //case "zip": $ctype="application/zip"; break;
  case "rar": $ctype="application/x-rar"; break;
  //case "doc": $ctype="application/msword"; break;
  //case "xls": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-excel"; break;
  //case "ppt": $ctype="application/vnd.ms-powerpoint"; break;
  //case "gif": $ctype="image/gif"; break;
  //case "png": $ctype="image/png"; break;
  //case "jpeg":
  //case "jpg": $ctype="image/jpg"; break;
  default: $ctype="application/force-download";
}

header("Pragma: public"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); 
header("Content-Type: $ctype");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($download_url)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".$fsize);
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile( $download_url );

  } 
   else echo "<div class='alert-box notice'><i class='fa fa-exclamation-circle' aria-hidden='true'></i> 
  This file could not be loaded... Contact an <a href='help'>an agent</a>.</div>";
  header( "refresh:3;url=myinventory");

 }
```

The problem is when someone downloads.. the file says "The archieve is either in unknown format or damaged".

How can i fix this big problem in my download system?
I try to many things but is the same...

Comment: How does `download_file()` work with an url? Shouldn't it be a file path? So, check the return value of `readfile()` to see whether you actually output something.

Comment: download_file() works with $download_url.. is a link via MYSQLI Record

Comment: Please read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL and compare this with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(computing). It might just be a naming issue, but how are we to know?

Comment: This is the URL "asp/img/listings/projects/5a711ae18f1194.97435269.1s.rar"

The file comes from a FOLDER.

Comment: So it's a naming issue, what you call an url is really a path. Variable names should be descriptive of their contents. Apart from that it would still be useful to check the return value of `readfile()`.

Comment: how can i check tue value of readfile()?

Comment: The manual tells you: http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php but if that's not clear use this: `$bytesRead = readfile($path); if ($bytesRead === FALSE) echo 'ERROR'; else echo $bytesRead.' bytes read';`

Comment: The read_path is right... hes reading the file.. and downloading... But when i click to Open de File says Broken... I try to download from my XAMMP folder.. and its ok...